# How to define Baggage add attach it to MDC using OpenTelemetry in Spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, open-telemetry, otel

I want to define a custom baggage that will be appended to the MDC logging using OpenTelemetry within Spring boot 3 application. Previously I was using Brave as a tracer, and this was my configuration

build.gradle:

```
...
    implementation 'io.micrometer:context-propagation:1.0.5'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
...
```

application.yml:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "health,info"
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0
    baggage:
      correlation:
        fields:
          - myBaggage
      remote-fields:
        - myBaggage
```

this is the configuration for defining the Bean and adding the field to the MDC:

```
@Configuration
public class LoggingContextConfig {

  @Bean
  BaggageField myBaggage() {
    return BaggageField.create("myBaggage");
  }

  @Bean
  ScopeDecorator mdcScopeDecorator() {
    return MDCScopeDecorator.newBuilder().clear()
        .add(SingleCorrelationField.newBuilder(myBaggage()).flushOnUpdate().build()).build();
  }
}
```

Now with switching to **'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'** I noticed some differences with this implementation, and I need help to achieve the similar behaviour.